"del" a list of variables, some which don't exist, without invoking globals()
In this Q&A, I describe why I wish to issue (say) del a,b,c where some of the variables do not exist.  All solutions work, but they make use of globals() because that is the prevailing namespace.  That is, I run a script and then work from the console.  The script is constantly changing, so hiving sections of it into functions is not practical.
However, I am finding that using globals() is not practical when some of the objects take a lot of memory.  For example, I have a list of 90+ thousand nested dictionaries read from a JSON file, which the ensuing code munges into a DataFrame.  Even invoking globals() by itself causes the Python console to freeze.  From trial an error I found the point at which it doesn't come back is about 20K records.
What is a good alternative to using globals() if I want to apply del to a list of variables names, only some of which exist?
The solution in the Q&A cited above uses try, but it still requires the invocation globals() to generate the dictionary to look up each variable in the list.  Here is the original version of that solution (it has since been modified):
def del_globals(*names):
   for name1 in names:
      try: del globals()[name1]
      except KeyError: pass # Ignore if name1 doesn't exist


"Even invoking globals() by itself causes the Python console to freeze" - What do you mean, "even"? Invoking globals() by itself (and having it printed) is probably faaaaar more expensive than doing something with it.

Is invoking globals problematic? If you do that in REPL, I expect that printing is a trouble, but not invocation itself. You can confirm with _ = globals() to avoid echoing - it should complete almost immediately.

@no comment: The reason I was playing around with globals() at the command line is because when I invoked the function that looks up each variable name globals(), it left the variables in the global namespace.  Strangely, it didn't crash, it just didn't delete them.  I haven't yet figured out why.

@user24714692: I pondered how to create a minimal working example.  The ingested JSON is very large.  I will think about how to generate a test data set programmatically (I'm new to Python).

@STerliakov: The test passes instantaneously, as does 'MyVariable' in globals().  There was another problem that I was trying to solve that caused me to play around with globals(), and it looks like crashing from printing globals() is not the cause for that other problem.  Thanks!

If it's relevant, here's another question where the printing was the slow part: Does the python interpreter implicitly use the Chinese remainder theorem? (about exponentiation followed by modulus)

@user2153235 For generating large data, there's some advice at How to make good reproducible pandas examples in Andy's answer under "performance issues"

"The script is constantly changing, so hiving sections of it into functions is not practical." This makes no sense. Using functions would make changing your code easier. Perhaps one of the few excuses to write code the way you are doing it is "oh I'm only writing this once and it isn't going to change"

@wjandrea: Thanks, but based on @STerliakov's tests, I ruled out the use of globals() as the cause of another error that I am trying to troubleshoot (basically, that the original solution seems to silently fails).  In reality, however, I think Spyder's Variable Explorer isn't being updated.

@user2153235 That's what I was going to ask next: how are you checking that the names still exist? If you're using IPython or something like it, it might hold onto the objects but not the names. Instead, checking the names with something like 'MyVariable' in globals() should confirm.

I added your (original) del_globals(*names) to the question posted above.  I tested it with del_globals('AISmsg1') and del_globals('AISmsg1','AISmsg1').  After each of these, sorted( globals().keys() )[0:5] yields ['AISmsg1', 'AISmsgs', 'JsonObj', 'MsgIDs', 'MsgNestedDict'] and 'AISmsg1' in globals() yields True.  After del globals()['AISmsg1'], however, 'AISmsg1' in globals() yields False and AISmsg1 disappears from the Variable Ex;plorer.

I used the Spyder debugger to step into del_globals().  The problem seems to be that globals() invoked from within del_globals() returns a very different dictionary than when invoked from the top level REPL prompt.  Within del_globals(), the globals() dictionary is very sparse, containing none of the variables from the namespace of the REPL prompt.

Why aren't you using @wjandrea 's fixed solution?

I'm aiming for streamlined code that adds as little as possible to the main code.  Ideally, it would have been just a del command that doesn't error out when given a non-existent variable.  I will give his modified code a try tomorrow and will likely find it to work based on this. It does, however, raise the question of why the global namespace changes based on scope.  If I can figure this out, I would prefer his leaner original solution.

Since del asdf raises NameError if the variable doesn't exist, you must use try with that exception type: try: del asdf; except NameError: pass. Being obsessed with globals(), as pointed out already, is an XY problem.

@user2153235 OMG... You're using the broken version. That's why I updated it: the original version didn't work properly if it was in a different module. Global variables are scoped per-module.

I'm learning that now.  The fixed version is lengthier to invoke, so I'm trying to see if I can make it work (with help on SO).  The more code, identifiers, and punctuation, the more noise it introduces, so I'll see what streamlining I can get away with in the invocation.

There is no (meaningfully distinct) alternative to gaining programmatic access to the globals by string name. But you're likely having issues only because you're trying to print the globals() dict (likely implicitly, since you're working interactively).
In an interactive console, doing >>> globals() is going to automatically echo what it just produced, which means trying to stringify and output the recursive repr of the entire dict, which, as you've seen, gets ugly when you've polluted the global namespace a lot, or even a little with large objects with complex reprs. Don't do that. But:
for k in globals().keys() & {'keys', 'to', 'delete', 'if', 'they', 'exist'}:
    del globals()[k]

or more efficiently (avoiding calling globals over and over, which isn't an expensive function, but it's still more expensive than accessing a variable, especially a function local):
# Defined once up front
def delete_keys_from_dict(dct, *keys):
    for k in dct.keys() & keys:
        del dct[k]

# Called as needed
delete_keys_from_dict(globals(), 'keys', 'to', 'delete', 'if', 'they', 'exist')

is perfectly safe; globals() does no scaling work (the dict already exists, globals() is just returning the reference to the existing dict), unlike locals() within a function (where every call has to refresh the values in the stack frame's f_locals dict - the dict isn't kept up to date during normal code execution), so if you're not echoing it, it won't freeze anything (if it appears to do so, it's because you've got something else consuming so much memory you're stuck page thrashing, which isn't something you can get around trivially).

I will note:

The script is constantly changing, so hiving sections of it into functions is not practical.

is a bad excuse for operating exclusively with global variables and no function locals. A script can change constantly and still have functions in it. Factoring out functionality into functions would get a lot of the benefits you want already (e.g. if one of the functions loads a metric ton of data into local variables, summarizes it, and returns the summary, the metric ton of data would be freed automatically by virtue of being a local that gets cleaned up when the function returns automatically). You've got an XY problem here, where you've selected an approach that is fundamentally flawed and non-scalable, and you're trying progressively more complicated workarounds for the flaws, when the solution is to go with a different approach that won't have these flaws in the first place.

I've written scripts and functions in other 4GL's before.  I think I have a good idea of when to hive code into functions.   I appreciate the code pattern you provided.  Right now, I'm troubleshooting the solution from the cited Q&A because it introduces the least additional code into the main body.  However, I may resort to yours if I can't figure out that one.  Thanks.

"gets ugly when you've polluted the global namespace a lot" - It's not really about pollution; I mean, even a single large object would do that.

@user2153235 Yeah, not using functions is fine IMO too. Like you said on the other question, you're not writing production code, you're writing exploratory data analysis.

@user2153235 I think you may have misunderstood how this code works. It's effectively the same as mine on the linked question, the only difference is it only tries to delete keys that are definitely present.

@wjandrea: Thanks, but I do recognize the similarity that you describe.  However, I had no idea what was causing yours to "fail".  It could have been something in the way that it was hived into a function, or my invocation of it. Currently, however, the most likely suspect is that Spyder's Variable Explorer isn't updating, i.e., your function works, but it just isn't showing.
